# Selecting Node with same names in XML with PHP - Confused

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following xml

```
<md f="a">
<![CDATA[ MR Adam Smith ]]>
</md>
<md f="b">
<![CDATA[ Smith, Adam ]]>
</md>
```

And I'm not sure how using PHP to echo the different md nodes using simplexml?
So my current code below can only bring the first value of md node - but how do I get the other values of md? I looked at namespace- but these seems different.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
foreach($xml->results->result as $usern)
{
    echo $usern->score . '<br>';
    echo $usern->md. '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this problem before. You need to change how you create the SimpleXML object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

[`LIBXML_NOCDATA`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) will ensure you can grab the values from CDATA text.

This is mentioned in the comments ([mario's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#85484) in particular) of the [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) documentation.